# MYSQL C# ошибка при вызове хранимой процедуры

Tags: c#, mysql

Добрый верчер.
Я на C# и MySql делал проект онлайн меню заказа еды.
на MYSQl я создал хранимую процедуру:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_pr1 (IN per VARCHAR(12), IN fd VARCHAR(60), IN fdo TEXT, IN pors INT)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO zakaz (persons, food, food_option, parth) VALUES (per, fd, fdo, pors);END
```

На C# вызиваю:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace menu_mysql
{
public partial class menu : Form
{


    public menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog='testmenu';username=root;password=");

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlParameter[] spr = new MySqlParameter[4];
        spr[0] = new MySqlParameter("per", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        spr[0].Value = textBox1.Text;

        spr[1] = new MySqlParameter("fd", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        spr[1].Value = comboBox1.Text;

        spr[2] = new MySqlParameter("fdo", SqlDbType.Text);
        spr[2].Value = textBox2.Text;

        spr[3] = new MySqlParameter("pors", SqlDbType.Int);
        spr[3].Value = comboBox2.Text;

        MySqlCommand comand = new MySqlCommand();

        comand.Connection = connect;
        comand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comand.CommandText = "my_sp1";

        comand.Parameters.AddRange(spr);

        connect.Open();
        if (comand.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yes");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No");
        }
        connect.Close();
    }
```

проблема в том что при запуске VS 2017 Community даёт ошибку что непрописаны значения для:

```
    if (comand.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
```

вопрос как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html

> Parameters that represent arguments to the procedure must have their
>   Direction property set to Input.

т.е.

> Свойство `Direction` входных параметров сохраненной процедуры должно
>   быть установлено в значение `Input`.

```
spr[0].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
// и т.д.
```

> как подключить combobox2 к зна...

Задайте другой вопрос на эту тему..

Comment: можно этим же кодом задавать второй вопрос?

Comment: @beginneroot Постарайтесь свести количество кода к минимально необходимому.

Comment: для каждой значании процедуры я должен прописать этот код spr[0].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;  //  spr[1].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input; тд. ?

Comment: @beginneroot да. Можете делать это в цикле, если все параметры входные: `foreach(MySqlParameter par in spr) par.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;`

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: ВЫдаёт ошибку что: System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: @beginneroot Этот цикл надо выполнять после создания параметров `spr[...] = new MySqlParameter(...);`, а не до.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67240/discussion-between-beginneroot-and-igor).

Comment: тут ошибка в том что процедура "Procedure or function '`my_sp1`' cannot be found in database '`testmenu`'."

Comment: @beginneroot `my_pr1 != my_sp1`